# Stack around the variable was corrupted when querying arrays in WMI

Tags: c++, winapi, wmi

I am trying to query an array of Uint16 in WMI, more specifically I am trying to retrieve the User-friendly name for the monitors which is stored in a Uint16[] in WMI. My code looks as follow:

```
template<> UInt16Vec _convertValue<UInt16Vec>(VARIANT& vtProp)
    {
        UInt16Vec uint16Array;

        if (V_VT(&vtProp) & (VT_ARRAY | VT_UINT))
        {
            long lBound = 0;
            long uBound = 0;
            HRESULT hresult = SafeArrayGetLBound(vtProp.parray, 1, &lBound);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hresult))
            {
                hresult = SafeArrayGetUBound(vtProp.parray, 1, &uBound);
            }

            if (SUCCEEDED(hresult))
            {
                long cnt_elements = uBound - lBound + 1;
                for (long i = 0; i < cnt_elements; ++i)
                {
                    UINT16 val;
                    hresult = SafeArrayGetElement(vtProp.parray, &i, &val);
                    uint16Array.push_back(SUCCEEDED(hresult) ? val : -1);
                }
            }
        }

        return uint16Array;
    }

 std::vector<UInt16Vec> WMIService::queryUInt16Array(bstr_t query, LPCWSTR value)
    {
        std::vector<UInt16Vec> vec;
        if (SUCCEEDED(mStatus) && pSvc)
        {
            _queryWMI<UInt16Vec>(pSvc, vec, query, value);
        }
        return vec;
    }

template<typename T>
    void WMIService::_queryWMI(IWbemServices *pSvc, std::vector<T> &vec, bstr_t query, LPCWSTR value, int index)
    {
        // Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI ----
        IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = nullptr;
        HRESULT hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
            bstr_t("WQL"),
            query,
            WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
            NULL,
            &pEnumerator);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hres) && pEnumerator != nullptr)
        {
            // Get the data from the query
            IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = NULL;
            ULONG uReturn = 0;
            int localIndex = 0;

            while (pEnumerator)
            {
                pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);

                if (0 == uReturn || (index>-1 && localIndex == index + 1))
                {
                    break;
                }

                VARIANT vtProp;
                if (SUCCEEDED(pclsObj->Get(value, 0, &vtProp, 0, 0)))
                {
                    vec.push_back(_convertValue<T>(vtProp));
                    VariantClear(&vtProp);
                }

                pclsObj->Release();

                ++localIndex;
            }
        }

        if (pEnumerator != nullptr)
        {
            pEnumerator->Release();
        }
    }
}
```

However at the end of _convertValue when I return uint16Array I get "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'val' was corrupted" and I am not sure why.

Comment: You forgot to call `SafeArrayGetDim` to determine how many dimensions there are. If this is a 2-dimensional (or more) array, you are passing only one dimension to `SafeArrayGetElement`, and the rest will be out-of-bounds. You are also reading a 4-byte integer (`VT_UINT`) into a two-byte variable (`UINT16`), which is a two-byte buffer overflow.

Comment: @RaymondChen Ah I see, thank you!